# Is there a convenient way to use a pattern as a predicate function?

Tags: haskell

I've recently been running into situations where I need to pass a predicate function into another function, and quite often the logic I am looking for is essentially "does this value match this pattern?"

Pattern matching seems to be preferred in declarations, `do` blocks, and list comprehensions, but there are a number of functions that take a predicate `a -> Bool`, where it would be very handy to somehow pass in a pattern. For example, `takeWhile`, `until`, `find`, `span`, etc.

Thus far I've been doing `\a -> case a of MyCons _ -> True; otherwise -> False`, or writing a named function a la `let myPred (MyCons _) = True; myPred _ = False in` but they both seem terribly ugly and not very idiomatic. The "obvious" (and wrong) way would be something like `\(MyCons _) -> True` but that throws an error for being partial, naturally, and even then it feels like there must be a cleaner way.

Is there a more succinct / clean way to do this sort of thing? Or am I going about things entirely the wrong way?

Comment: Maybe this is a "personal taste" thing but, if you only need this predicate in one place, I'd be quite happy with the `let` clause that you dislike - although I prefer the equivalent `where` clause so this doesn't clutter the main definition. Of course if you end up needing this utility more than once then you would define it as a top level function.

Comment: It certainly works fine. My question was somewhat motivated by how impressively succinct Haskell typically is. It usually feels like idiomatic Haskell has very little duplication of ideas, and keeps fluff to a minimum. So it's not even necessarily that I think the `let myPred...` style is *bad*, but it feels much more verbose than I would expect for a very simple idea, which leads me to wonder if I am barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: You might have a look at prisms (from lens). They are like first-class composable patterns

Comment: I think we'd need to seen an example of where you are using this type of higher-order function. Part of me wants to say the problem is with the design that requires such a predicate in the first place.

Comment: the Haskell98 way, for this, is to define the case-matching (deconstructing) function for your data type, like `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` and `bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a`, then use it with Boolean-producing function(s) as argument(s). e.g. `myCons z f (MyCons x) = f x ; myCons z f _ = z`, then call `myCons False (const True) aMyConsValue`. this is almost what you wrote, just has one more level of "indirection" / "abstraction" via functional argument(s), baked into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Language Extension LambdaCase to use `\case MyCons _ -> True; _ -> False`, although this doesn't save that many characters.

I believe you could write a series of functions `constructedWith :: (Generic a) => (b -> a) -> a -> Bool`, `constructedWith2 :: (Generic a) => (b -> c -> a) -> a -> Bool`, but I'm not competent enough with Generics to implement it without a few hours testing things out. I will try this, and edit my answer if I can figure it out, or if it is a dead end.

EDIT: Yes, you can do it! Here's a link to my code, which implements it all from scratch:

https://repl.it/@lalaithion/ConstructedWith

However, using something like http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.13.1/docs/Generics-Deriving-ConNames.html for all of the generic code plumbing might be better.